# Predictor for averaged Brownian motion

Tags: forecasting, stochastic-processes, gaussian-process, random-walk, brownian-motion

The best forecast (predictor) for a Brownian motion at time $t+h$ is the present value at time $t$ since it's a martingale. The same holds for random walks with independent steps and without drift.

Now assume you observe a Brownian motion $B(t)$ not in a point-wise fashion, but through its average on a sequence of intervals of size 1: $x_k=\int_{k-1}^k B(t)dt$.

1. Are the steps of $x_k$ independent?
2. If not, what is the best forecast for $x_{k+1}$ ? I mean what is $E(x_{k+1}|x_k,x_{k-1},...)$ ?

Any idea of a method to use?

Comment: Let $y_k=\int_0^kB_tdt$. Then $x_k=y_k-y_{k-1}$. Now apply Ito's lemma to calculate $dx_t$ and $dy_t$, to see which of them, if any, are martingales

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $B_t$ denote the state of the Brownian motion at each discrete time point $t=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\dots$.  Clearly, $B_t$ follows a random walk model
$$
(1-L)B_t = w_t \tag{1}
$$
where $L$ is the backshift operator and $w_t$ is Gaussian white noise with variance $\sigma^2$.

In-between two time points $t-1$ and $t$, conditional on $B(t-1)=B_{t-1}$ and $B(t)=B_t$, $B(t)$ is distributed as a [Brownian bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge).  It follows that the integral $x_t=\int_{t-1}^t B(t) dt$ of the bridge is normally distributed with conditional expectation $\frac12(B_t+B_{t-1})$.  Using [this formula for the covariance between $B(s)$ and $B(t)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge), the conditional variance is
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(x_t|B_t,B_{t-1})
  &=\operatorname{Var}(x_1|B(1)=0,B(0)=0)
\\&=E\left(\int_0^1 B(t)dt\int_0^1 B(s)ds\right)
\\&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 E(B(t)B(s))dsdt
\\&=2\int_0^1 \int_0^t \sigma^2 s(1-t) dsdt
\\&=\frac{\sigma^2}{12}.
\end{align}
In other words, 
$$
x_t = \frac12(1+L)B_t + u_t, \tag{2}
$$
a moving average of the random walk $B_t$ plus white noise $u_t$ with variance $\sigma^2/12$.

Applying $(1-L)$ to both sides of (2) and using (1) yields
$$
(1-L)x_t = \frac12(1+L)w_t + (1-L)u_t. \tag{3}
$$
The right hand side of (3) is the sum of first order moving averages of two independent white noise processes and hence itself a first order moving average process that can be represented by $(1+\theta L)v_t$ where $v_t$ is another white noise process.  Overall, $x_t$ thus satisfies a standard ARIMA(0,1,1) time series model
$$
(1-L)x_t = (1+\theta L)v_t. \tag{4} 
$$
The moving average parameter $\theta$ and
the variance of $v_t$ in (4) can be determined by equating the autocovariance functions of the right hand sides of (3) and (4).  This leads to
$$
\theta = 2-\sqrt{3}
$$
and 
$$
\sigma_v^2 = \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}6 \sigma^2.
$$

From (4) it is apparent that the increments $\Delta x_t =(1-L)x_t$ are not independent but follow an MA(1) process.  The correlation between $\Delta x_t$ and $\Delta x_{t-1}$ is $\theta/(1+\theta^2)=1/4$.

Forecasting of $x_{t+1}$ can now be done using standard methods.  The infinite history forecast via the pure autoregressive AR$(\infty)$ representation of (4) is given by 
$$
E(x_{t+1}|x_t,x_{t-1},\dots)=(1+\theta)(x_t - \theta x_{t-1} + \theta^2 x_{t-2} - \theta^3 x_{t-3} + \dots), \tag{5}
$$
a geometrically weighted average of past observations (red line segment in Figure below).  Given that $\theta$ is quite small (0.2679), the forecast depends strongly only on the last few observations.

[image]

Alternatively, an exact finite history forecast can be computed via the state space representation of (4) using the Kalman filter but this will not differ much from (5) unless only a small number of observations are available.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed and beautiful answer. $\theta$ does not depend on $\sigma^2$. It thus neither depends on the length on the intervals (if it wasn't $1$)... Interesting.