Is an integrated exponential alternating renewal process a Markov chain?
Consider an alternating renewal process where the alternating extents are independent exponentially distributed with means, mu_0 and mu_1. The alternating extents determine whether the outcome at any instant is a zero or a one. So we see an extent showing zero followed by an extent showing one, etc. Imagine that those binary outcomes are averaged over consecutive abutting windows of constant width. We'll called those averages the binary fractions. Are those binary fractions a Markov chain process, that is, where the probability distribution of the next fraction is only determined by the current fraction.
My logic suggests it isn't. As a simplification of this problem, assume we have a discrete binary (0,1) Markov chain process. We overlay separate contiguous windows of constant length, 2, and measure the proportion of time (the binary fraction) that the chain within each window is in state one, being one of (0, 0.5 or 1). Now clearly the outcome for the current fraction is dependent on the result for the previous fraction. This is due to the Markov chain relationship between the last of the two contributing (Markov chain) outcomes for the current window and the first for the previous window. This suggests in itself that the relationship between fractions finishes there and we have a Markov chain.
However we don't exactly know the complete outcome for the two values of the original series making up that lag-one relationship in the original series (All we have are the binary fractions from each window). Some (albeit incomplete but nonetheless contributory) idea of their values is in fact provided by the information in the fraction another window further into the past. Hence the current fraction is related to the fraction one step into the past (due to the Markov chain property) and also two steps into the past (due to the information augmentation from the lag-two fraction). Hence this isn't a Markov chain process.
To illustrate further, using the above illustration, imagine that the lag-one fraction is 0.5. This suggest that there is a priori a 0.5 chance that the underlying series values are 0,1 (with the most recent value to the left) and 0.5 that they are 1,0. However imagine further that the lag-two fraction is 1 which means a 1,1 outcome for the contributing series. If the Markov chain process involves transition probabilities reflecting “sticky” states with relatively low chances of switching then the underlying series values for the lag-one window is more likely to be 0,1 than 1,0. This in turn influences the lag-zero fraction thereby defying the definition of a Markov chain.
This overall reasoning can be extended to the exponential alternating renewal process being a continuous Markov chain. Essentially the number of the original series in each window approaches infinity and the non-switching probability approaches 1-delta*lambda as delta -> 0 (where delta is the interval between recordings of state) but the logic is the same. Hence integration of an exponential alternating renewal process doesn't "seem" to result in a Markov chain process.

I also think that the resulting process is not a Markov chain.  Some links that may be relevant are https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405510/occupation-times-for-two-state-markov-processes and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466836/closed-form-of-series-with-factorial-squared-denominator.   I provide an answer to a similar question involving a similar moving average of an underlying continuous-time process where the underlying process is instead Gaussian at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/313125/77222.

Jarle, thank you for your comments and for the links. I was hoping that the result would be a Markov process in order to apply that theory to the outcome. But it looks pretty certain that this isn't the case.
